# NullPointer injecting EntityManager with Guice-persist in SparkJava application

Tags: java, hibernate, guice, entitymanager, spark-java

I'm having problems trying to inject an EntityManager in a Spark + Guice application.

My persistence.xml is:

```
<persistence-unit name="jpa-persistence-unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <!-- JPA entities must be registered here -->
    <...>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="A.Special.Customized.SQLiteDialect" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:local.db" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My main method goes (in App.java)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new JpaPersistModule("jpa-persistence-unit"));
    injector.getInstance(App.class).run();
}
```

And I'm trying to inject this way, in an object managed by guice (in DeputyService.java)

```
@Inject
private EntityManager em;
```

Two important facts:

1. In the run method of App I start the PersistService
2. Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think the problem is with sqlite. I say this because without trying to inject the entityManager the application boots alright and even create the database and tables.

(if you are feeling extra helpful and need more details of the setup, feel free to ask or reach the project at https://github.com/vitallan/politicaaberta-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, Google Guice injects a provider, not the entityManager specifically speaking.

So, changing the injection from

```
@Inject
private EntityManager em;
```

to

```
@Inject
private Provider<EntityManager> em;
```

solved the problem.